# How can I control my Kobuki base Turtlebot with a NI myRIO?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a part of a senior design group that is charged with building an autonomous robot that has to be controlled by the NI myRIO. The goal of the project is to make the robot follow a person or object using a Kinect sensor. Everything has to be coded in LabVIEW, as well. How can I achieve connectivity between all three devices? Is it even possible to make the Kobuki base and the myRIO communicate with each other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226500/how-can-i-control-my-kobuki-base-turtlebot-with-a-ni-myrio?/) by [chanel27](https://answers.ros.org/users/25934/chanel27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-02-13**:
you had posted this twice, so I closed one, to keep all answers/comments in the same location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For general integration with a larger ROS application, there is an (experimental) package for Labview that allows semi-transparent communication between a ROS node graph and Labview: [ROSforLabview](https://sites.google.com/site/rosforlabview/), created by Chris Rogers from Tufts University (Sine page here: [Introducing LabVIEW and the Robot Operating System (ROS)](http://sine.ni.com/cs/app/doc/p/id/cs-16503)).

For just communicating with the base, you'll probably have to follow the suggestion of @nickw.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0